# Should I worry about UUID uniqueness

Tags: uuid

I am using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuidv4 module to identify uniqueness of the user. Should I worry that 2 people might get the same uuid? What if I store of all given uuids for the day and before I give new uuids I check if it already exists in the database? And then after a day I would empty my database and repeat the process. Is it a good approach? Am I missing anything?

Comment: uuids are designed to make it very, very unlikely that you get the same value twice. Virtually impossible, so don't worry about it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I worry that 2 people might get the same uuid...

No you shouldn't. UUID's are unique for *practical* purposes.

From [Wikipedia: UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions):

> ..., the number of random version 4 UUIDs which need to be generated in order to have a 50% probability of at least one collision is 2.71 quintillion...

As for:

> What if I store of all given uuids for the day and before I give new uuids I check if it already exists in the database

You should have a [Unique Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) constraint on your table. Even if you do get a collision the DB would reject it.

Comment: Indeed, you can even [sacrifice some UUID uniqueness to get better primary key performance](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25862) for ex. COMB guids.

Answer (score -5):

Yes you should (and so should we). By following the standard procedure, one gets pretty unique UUIDs. But evil players can intentionally cause collisions, since there is no central registry for UUIDs. So, these days, extra caution with UUIDs won't harm.

Comment: "Intentionally cause collisions" if the generation job is done on the client, maybe. That's awful design, though -- the easy answer is "don't do that". If you're going to argue that collisions of type-4 UUIDs can be triggered without trusting the client (or having sufficient control of the server as to effectively constitute having rooted the service already), please show a published instance of such an attack.